# Smart Map search not working with Province

Tags: templating, plugin-smartmap

I'm building out a store locator map and everything is going well. All store locations get output on the map and when I search with either a city or a postal code the map filters the results correctly. However if I add in a province, whether the full name or abbreviation) there are no results.

I'm not sure how to resolve this. The form is above the map with this code:

```
{% set formPost = craft.request.getPost('query') %}
{% if formPost %}
  {#
    testing what the post variable is equal to
    will use this to set different options in map

  {{ formPost }} - this is a post variable
  #}
{% else %}
  {% set formPost = "noPost" %}
{% endif %}

{#
  // use this post variable and a conditional to  filter the map
#}

<form action="/store/find" method="post">
    <input type="search" name="query" id="query" class="form-control" placeholder="City, Province or Postal Code" >
    <button class="btn btn-primary find-a-store-form__button" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

The map is rendered with the following code using conditionals to check if a post variable exists.

```
{% if formPost == "noPost" %}
  {# no filter find all stores, this is before searching #}
  {% set allStores = craft.entries.section('stores').limit(1000).find() %}

{% else %}
 {# search filters via post variable #}

 {% set target = formPost %}
 {% set params = {
   target: target,
   range: 100,
   units: "kilometers"
 } %}
  {% set allStores = craft.entries.mapAddress(params).order('distance').find() %}
{% endif %}

{{ craft.smartMap.map(allStores, options) }}
```

So searching with a city or postal code works, but searching with a province (fullname or abbreviation) does not work.

-------UPDATE----------

Was recommended to move the province search to a dropdown. I've since set that up but now results do not work for either the input field or the select. I'm not sure why.

Current template code:

```
{% set queryPost = craft.request.getPost('query') %}
{% set provincePost = craft.request.getPost('province') %}

{# does post data exist? #}
{% set formPost = craft.request.getPost() | length %}

{% if formPost %}
  {#
    testing what the post variable is equal to
    will use this to set different options in map

  {{ formPost }} - this is a post variable
  #}
{% else %}
  {% set formPost = "noPost" %}
{% endif %}

{#
  // use this post variable and a conditional to  filter the map
#}
<form action="/store/find" method="post">
    <input type="search" name="query" id="query" class="form-control" placeholder="City, Province or Postal Code" >
    <select name="province" id="province" class="form-control">
        <option selected>--select province--</option>
        <option value="Alberta">Alberta</option>
        <option value="British Columbia">British Columbia</option>
        <option value="Manitoba">Manitoba</option>
        <option value="New Brunswick">New Brunswick</option>
        <option value="Newfoundland and Labrador">Newfoundland and Labrador</option>
        <option value="Nova Scotia">Nova Scotia</option>
        <option value="Ontario">Ontario</option>
        <option value="Prince Edward Island">Prince Edward Island</option>
        <option value="Quebec">Quebec</option>
        <option value="Saskatchewan">Saskatchewan</option>
        <option value="Northwest Territories">Northwest Territories</option>
        <option value="Nunavut">Nunavut</option>
        <option value="Yukon">Yukon</option>
      </select>
    <button class="btn btn-primary find-a-store-form__button" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>

</header>

<div class="find-a-store-form__map">


{#
  // default map options - all stores
  // remove the center option on search results let map decide center
#}

{% if formPost == "noPost" %}
  {# options for default map #}
  {% set options = {
      id: 'storeLocator',
      height: 615,
      width: 1090,
      zoom: findAStore.zoomLevel,
      zoomControl: true,
      draggable: true,
      center: {
        'lat':findAStore.mapCenterLatitude,
        'lng':findAStore.mapCenterLongitude
      },
      markerInfo: '_includes/mapInfoBubble',
      markerOptions: {
          icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png'
      },
      infoWindowOptions: {
          maxWidth: 200
      }
  } %}
  {# end default map options #}

{% else %}


  {# begin filtered map options i.e. no center set #}
  {% set options = {
      id: 'storeLocator',
      height: 615,
      width: 1090,
      zoom: 7,
      zoomControl: true,
      draggable: true,
      markerInfo: '_includes/mapInfoBubble',
      markerOptions: {
          icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png'
      },
      infoWindowOptions: {
          maxWidth: 200
      }
  } %}
  {# end filtered map otions #}
{% endif %}



{% if formPost == "noPost" %}
  {# no filter find all stores, this is before searching #}
  {% set allStores = craft.entries.section('stores').limit(1000).find() %}

{% else %}
 {# search filters via post variable #}

 {% set target = formPost %}
 {% set params = {
     target: target,
     range: 100,
     units: "kilometers",
     'components': {
          'administrative_area': 'provincePost',
      },
    }
  %}

  {% set allStores = craft.entries.mapAddress(params).order('distance').find() %}
{% endif %}

{{ craft.smartMap.map(allStores, options) }}

</div>
```

In the above code this bit, near the bottom `'administrative_area': 'provincePost',` I've had provincePost both with and without quotes but that didn't help.